# Views inside CoordinatorLayout are overlapped by system buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-support-library

How to solve this problem so LinearLayout will be adjacent to or fitted right to system buttons? Does replacing of GridView to RecycleView solve it? Currently I've solved this by adding some margin for the last element in the GridView adapter but I think there should be a better, more straightforward way.

[image: preview]

Here is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/fragmnetLayout"
            android:theme="@style/LayoutsStyle" >

            <fragment
                class="com.example.AlbumsFragment"
                android:id="@+id/albumsFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_albums.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/albumGridView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:theme="@style/LayoutsStyle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

album_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="left">

<com.example.SquareImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/albumImageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out how to solve my problem in this particular case.
Just delete "scroll" in toolbar's layout_scrollFlags. Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```